# Convert iterator objects from findAll to images in Sikuli after sorting

Tags: sorting, jython, sikuli

So I'm having an issue working with Sikuli.  There's a situation where multiple occurrences of an image exist.  To grab all of them, you can simply do a findAll, but it saves each image as some sort of object, rather than the image.  I know that you can get the images by using getLastMatches(), but I want to sort it first.  So here's the code that I got that grabs all the images and sorts them.  I found some of the information on the Sikuli documentation

```
def by_y(match):
  return match.y

icons = findAll(image)
sorted_icons = sorted(icons, key=by_y)
```

The problem with this, though, is that sorted_icons contains a bunch of iterable objects (at least that's what I saw them called), and not the images.  Is there a way to revert back to an image while keeping the new list sorted?  Using getLastMatches() gives a list of the original unsorted list.

Also, it's Sikuli 1.0.1.

Thanks.

This should illustrate the problem (hopefully).  In order to sort the images by their y value, I have to use the findAll() operation (if there is a way of doing this without using find then please share).  However, this converts the image from a string, i.e.:

```
"imagename.png"
```

into... well whatever this is (match?):

```
M[8,1045 37x28]@S(S(0)[0,0 1920x1080]) S:1.00 Center:26,1059
```

the self.assets.getimage(image) function requires a string, though (so the imagename.png) rather than the funky thing you get out of using find.

```
def exampleMethod(image, dx=0, dy=0):
    click(Pattern(self.assets.getimage(image)).targetOffset(dx, dy))

def by_y(match):
  return match.y

image = "imagename.png"
icons = findAll(image)
sorted_icons = sorted(image, key=by_y)

exampleMethod(sorted_icons[0])
```

Therefore, I need 1 of 2 things:

1. A way to convert the find object back to a String AFTER sorting
2. A way to sort the images by their y values while keeping the images as strings

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: My I ask what you'd like to do with the images? A `find` or `findAll`  operation uses a pattern/picture/screenshot or string as an input type and returns (a) match object(s), through which you can accomplish pretty much anything Sikuli has to offer...

Comment: there's a lot of pre-existing methods that require an image not a pattern.  Each of them uses find methods (along with self built methods similar to find).  I COULD put some if statements in to deal with this, but it would be a LOT of changes that I'd prefer not to do.  Therefore, I'd prefer to be able to just convert them back to images and send them to the methods

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear--What is the difference between an image and a pattern? In your example above, `icons = findAll(image)` the "image" here is of type Pattern. By contrast, if you were to say, `iconNames = findAll("IconTitle"), then IconTitle would be of type String. The only two types a findAll() operation accepts are a Pattern and a String. Are you meaning pattern and image to be the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, "image" refers to the String I guess.  So in my code, I use the findAll method, which converts the string to... whatever it becomes.  The methods I have to call after doing that also contain the find method.  However, since the image is no longer an image/string, the find method will not accept it.  In other words, the methods I'm calling are trying to do this:
find(findAll(image))  
and it doesn't like that.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to say, but are you sure you actually need a second find operation? whether it's a string or a pattern/picture that you've originally looked for, usually a find() is only preliminary to whatever else you want to do. And because you've already found it once, you can probably skip finding it a second time, and go directly on to whatever you were going to do. Could you post some code?

Comment: Additionally, it doesn't like the find(findAll(image) because the findAll(image) returns a list of Matches, but the find() operation cannot accept Matches as a parameter (which, I assume, is why you wanted to have the original images back?). If you need to find the images a second time, performing another findAll(image) (without the extra find() on the front) would be the way to do it.

Comment: I added some stuff that hopefully helps.  Obviously, that's not the ACTUAL code, but it should show the problem.  And yes, what you said about the matches is the issue.  However, I can't send that in with the getimage method that I added above.  It's grabbing a value from a dictionary using a string as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick info. JePySi doesn't deal with dynamic allocation of icons/images. This needs to be completly implemented with Sikuli features. So autoKarma is right `self.assets.getImage()` is useless in this context, since it only accessses pre-registered images which are addressed by name only. Hence only string operations.

Cheers,
  Alex - I wrote JePySi :-)

Comment: woah, did you use JePySi or actually write it? As in the developer of JePySi? lol Do you know of a good way to do this, then?  I can technically get away with putting a click(match) in a try/except statement, with the command "assert testcontext.browser.failed(...)" in it, and that would still allow it to be logged. It would just be nice to find a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will answer your question specifically, but I think there is a more direct way to accomplish your purpose.

Your `exampleMethod()` is a reiteration of the built-in `click()` function--

A `click()` will click on a Pattern, String, Location, Region or (most importantly for this question) Match just fine, so you don't really need the image back in order to click on it. You also don't need self.assets.getimage() to access an image to click on. The `click()` function implicitly does a `find()` operation first, then clicks on whatever it found. Since yours will be clicking on a Match object, it will just go to the coordinates provided by the match object and click on those coordinates.

Also, the default `.targetOffset` is (0, 0) (meaning it will click on the center of the found image). So, you may not need to pre-define as it 0 in your exampleMethod().

In sum, if there are several identical copies of the same image on a page, and you'd like to click on each one in order going down the screen, you can do something like this:

```
icons = list([x for x in findAll(image)]) #cast matches from the findAll() into a list 
sorted_icons = sorted(icons, key=by_y) #note 'icons' here and not 'image'
for icon in sorted_icons:  
    click(icon)
    #anything else you want to do with them
```

Another way to do it, without using Python's list comprehension (in case that's unfamiliar to you):

```
findAll(images)
icons = getLastMatches()
sorted_icons = sorted(icons, key=by_y)
listOfSortedIcons = []
while sorted_icons.hasNext():
    listOfSortedIcons.append(sorted_icons.next())
for icon in listOfSortedIcons:
    click(icon)
    #whatever else...
```

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be icons in there.  But I'm using Jepysi (a Python version of Ruby+Cucumber).  I just didn't state it because nobody seems to know about it anyway.  It is supposed to be a replicate of click().  However, in the method for it, it uses the "name.endswith()" method, which requires a String.  Therefore, a String has to be sent in, not a match.  I guess my example may not have been the most effectively made.

Comment: the "getimage(image)" method uses the endswith(), and it's not something I can remove due to its connections with the assets in the feature file.